# What are the effects of dead containers on open-shift cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

Does dead containers hold the IP addresses assigned to them? or IP's are released after they are dead? If I want to remove them and Somehow if I am not able to do so What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

Look at docker prune api to remove dead containers and other orphan ojbects

Comment: What about the IP's? Do containers still hold them or they are released when the containers die?

Comment: The IP is associated with the pod, not the container. I would expect the IP to be available for re-use once the pod has been deleted, or marked as terminated.

Comment: True. Services also occupy ip addresses. You need to delete services as well